# How to use two confirm dialog box?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a link button that display a confirm dialog box on click and on confirming the dialog box I have to search in database and if value is found then again it should display confirm dialog box and on confirming the dialog box then again have to do some searching task. For better understanding I have attached the flowchart.

[image]

Aspx Page

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function confirm_payslip() {
                            var res = confirm("Are you sure to upload current month payslip data");
                            if (res) {
                                //return true;
                                document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "1";
                               var myName = <%=this.firstName%>;
                               if(myName==1)
                               {
                               var result = confirm("Payslip Already Uploaded. Do you want to replace it?");
                               if(result)
                               {
                               document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "2";
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "0";
                                return false;
                               }
                               }
                            }
                            else {

                                document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "0";
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;                         //document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_div_PayTax").className = "loading"; 
                        }
        </script>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_payslip" runat="server" OnClientClick="confirm_payslip();" OnClick="lbtn_payslip_Click">Upload PaySlip Data</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

CS Page

```
public int firstName = 0;
    protected void lbtn_payslip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HiddenField1.Value == "1")
            {
                qry = "select count(*) from tbl_payslip_prn_t";
                dt = con.Execute(qry);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    firstName = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                     firstName = 0;
                     //Do Some task
                }
            }
            else if (HiddenField1.Value == "2")
            {
                //Do some task
            }
            else
            {
                firstName = 0;
                return;
            }
    }
```

The problem is the second dialog box runs in even number like on 2nd click, 4th click and so on. So how to achieve the above task ?

Comment: I'd suggest to use webparts, as seprating the logic in client (JS) and server (C#) side isn't the best way to code, as it becomes difficult to manage and maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My method is bit different but it will make you achieve what you want.

cs Page:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HiddenField1.Value.Trim() == "0")
        {
            return;
        }
        qry = "select count(*) from tbl_payslip_prn_t";
        dt = con.Execute(qry);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "exampleScript", "if(confirm(\"Payslip Already Uploaded. Do you want to replace it?\")){ document.getElementById('Button1').click(); }", true);
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Some task
        }
    }  
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Some Task    
    }
```

aspx Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function confirm_payslip() {
            var res = confirm("Are you sure to upload current month payslip data");
            if (res) {
                //return true;
                document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "1";
            }
            else {

                document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "0";
                return;
            }
        }
    </script>
 <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="confirm_payslip();" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden asp:Button on your aspx and attach a event handler to it and write the code that you want to have executed upon clicking Yes on the confirm button.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MyScript", "if(confirm(\"Payslip Already Uploaded. Do you want to replace it?\")){ document.getElementById('Button1').click(); }", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this demo may help?
http://jsfiddle.net/r8vf9pyw/

```
function confirm_payslip() {
  var myName = document.getElementById('myName').value;
  var input = document.getElementById('HiddenField1');
  var method;

  var res = confirm('Are you sure to upload current month payslip data');
  if (res) {
    if(myName==1) {
      var result = confirm("Payslip Already Uploaded. Do you want to replace it?");
      if(result) {
        input.value = "upload and replace it";
        method = 'upload';
      } else {
        input.value = "file exists, do not upload";
        method = 'abort';
      }
    } else {
      input.value = "upload new file";
      method = 'upload';
    }
  } else {
    input.value = 'upload aborted';
    method = 'abort';
  }

  if ('upload' === method) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Uploading...';
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Failed. Upload aborted';
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: quiet useful but this is not what I want. Since I have to fetch data from database after the confirmation of first dialog box and on behalf of that show the second dialog box